How to implement a blacklist feature for a Discord bot
So I'm writing a custom bot in python that has a variety of functions for my server, and I'm wanting to write a function/feature where it can effectively blacklist members regardless of whether they are in the server or not. That being said, I don't want the feature to ban members, as my server has a policy of, instead of banning people outright, they are given a specific role ('clown') that bars them from communicating in any channel except for a role-specific channel (aptly named 'circus'). Right now I'm thinking of implementing a command that extracts a user's ID into a blacklist.json file, then checks for the ID in the json and assigns the role accordingly. Thing is, I'm having trouble actually getting it to work. Any help would be appreciated.
My existing code is available here through this github gist: https://gist.github.com/L4w1i3t/68f118d93b456272c9d7e34f951cc161

Isolate your code. This will lead to a better question

"I'm having trouble actually getting it to work"; did you get an error ? Did you try printing out the user id, the content of your json or the role you are trying to add ? Please update your question with these informations.

It looks like your code has everything it needs as you've stored the blacklist in a .json and iterate through the guild members to find any matches - all that's needed is to schedule the function for the blacklist so that it repeats at a regular interval using tasks or an equivalent scheduler
@tasks.loop(hours = 3)
async def blacklist_loop():
    blacklist()


myLoop.start()

